# jQuery How to apply custom loading for images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="page-loading-wrapper">
    <div style="width: 168px" class="slide-content">
        <div class="loading-panel" style="background-color: #dddddd; height: 120px; position: relative">
            <div class="loading-text"><span class="loading-number">0</span>%</div>
            <div class="loading-load">LOADING</div>
        </div>
        <img src="images/shkeer-loading.png" width="168" height="91" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="loading-bottom-line"></div>
</div>

<div id="maximage">
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg.jpg" width="1580" height="889" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg2.jpg" width="1352" height="748" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg3.jpg" width="1285" height="803" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg4.jpg" width="1290" height="807" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg5.jpg" width="1295" height="921" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg6.jpg" width="1280" height="750" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/bg/bg7.jpg" width="1280" height="750" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and this Javascript code:

```
$('#maximage').maximage({
        onImagesLoaded: function() {
                    $(".page-loading-wrapper").slideUp("slow");
                },
        cycleOptions: {
            fx:'scrollHorz',
            autostopCount: 1,
            autostop: 1
        }
    });
```

and this code for loading:

```
function changeLoading() {

        var height = parseInt($(".loading-panel").height()) + 5;
        $(".loading-panel").css("height", height + "px");
        if ( height == 325) {
            clearInterval(t);
            var t2 = setInterval(changeNum, 110);   
        }
    }

function changeNum() {
        var n = parseInt($(".loading-number").html()) + 1;
        $(".loading-number").html(n);

        if ( n == 100) {
            clearInterval(t2);  
        }

    }
var t = setInterval(changeLoading, 10);
```

I'm using MaxCycle (Fullscreen Slideshow for use with jQuery Cycle Plugin)
and I'm trying to display loading bar while loading all images because they're very big about 150kb for each image.

[Demo](http://www.shkeer.info/shkeer/)

My loading bar is not fully functional as you can see. it just count until **MaxCycle** is loaded

```
                 onImagesLoaded: function() {
                    $(".page-loading-wrapper").slideUp("slow");
                }
```

So how I can make this loading works 100% specially the percent number, to check each image is loaded or not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean loading bar or progress bar?

Comment: progress bar, what is the difference anyway? just want the percent number to be right and display right information to the user

Comment: [Difference](https://jazz.net/library/article/122) if you realy don't know. And an [example](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/files/XHRProgressSample.html?file=XHRProgressSample.html)